# Is "this'll" considered proper English?

Tags: contractions

I understand that certain words when used over time are then embraced into the English lexicon. Is "this'll" one of those words?

Examples:

> This'll do.
>
> This'll stay in place.
>
> As an insert, this'll be easier to do.

Comment: From the song [*American Pie*](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=GV4RXInZDszIjwTy56iYBQ&q=this%27ll+be+the+day+that+I+die&oq=this%27ll+be+the+day+that+I+die&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i30l5.1760.4894..5045...0.0..0.111.1871.22j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i10.QbABlui7TNs), "*Singin' this'll be the day that I die*."

Comment: Do you really, really mean "proper" English? Do you mean "formal" English, instead? ***-'ll*** suffixed words like the above are "correct" but not entirely "formal".

Comment: @JasonBassford Is *singin'* "proper" English?

Comment: It has been "embraced" way long ago.

Answer (score 2):

It is a perfectly normal contraction, in daily use by millions of English speakers.

It is also widely used in informal writing. Many people regard contractions of this sort as inappropriate for more formal writing.

Whether you regard it as "a word" or not is up to you.

Comment: "Whether you regard it as "a word" or not is up to you." Then how is it "perfectly normal contraction"? Or vice versa?

Comment: @Kris: there is no universally agreed meaning of _word_. Is a contraction a word? If so, then _this'll_ is one.

Comment: How widely practised is informal writing nowadays? Texting, maybe.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Texting, tweeting, emails to friends, Facebook, Whatsapp...

Comment: 'Writing' still defaults to the hand-written variety in most of the dictionaries I've checked in. How English 'textspeak' etc are is another matter.

Comment: Not a great deal of handwriting, formal or informal, I would guess. I suppose that exams are one of the main contexts.

Answer (score 1):

"This'll" is an example of a word that is spoken aloud frequently but is not part of standard written English. Even if one is writing with other contractions (can't, won't, I'll, etc.), "this'll" would not be written down and would instead be expanded as "this will."

Comment: Hmm. It would never occur to me to expand _this'll_ in a context where I would write _he'll_. But I concede that the iWeb corpus shows only 3 401 instances of _this'll_ against 1 106 480  of _this will_ - a ratio of 1:325. This compares with 226 568 against 2 916 449 (1:13) for _it'll/it will_, and 205 744 against 636 339 (1:3) for, _he'll/he will_. I wonder why this should be. It could be simply that "he will" is more likely to occur in informal contexts than "it will" or "this will" - but I don't know whether that is the case or not.

Comment: Whence comes the bland statement that _this'll_ "is not part of standard written English"? Is there an index available where this can be looked up, or does one merely bow to the obvious correctness of the view?

Comment: @John Lawler BlandStatementsRUs.

Comment: Please give supporting evidence (I've taken the easier option of not doing the large amount of research required, and not venturing an 'answer'.)